# In swagger post parameters on registration

Tags: swagger

With api 3 version I want to make register enntry, with most common fields :
name, email, password, password_confirmation
I needs somewhow to describe POST parameters, looks like that is not parameters?
I tried to make as :

```
  /register:
    post:
      tags:
        - user account
      summary: Register user
      operationId: postRegister
#      parameters:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful registration
          content:
            application/json:
        '400':
          description: Invalid register data
```

1) How can I describe POST parameters ?
2) I checking http://petstore.swagger.io/ examples and I do not see any Register/login functionality.
Are there some other examples  Register/login functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/

Comment: Thanks! Are there some  examples with Register/login/token return ?

Comment: How is this different from any other POST operations with request bodies, such as the examples provided in the docs?

Comment: I mean login has to return token , which would be used for later requests to personal area. That is clear how to get token from login, but how to provide it for next requests?